# How to Compare two range's Range.Value2 with C#

Tags: c#, excel, compare

Here is my code

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Range col1 = r1.Columns[i];
Excel.Range col2 = r2.Columns[j];
```

Is there a quick method for me to compare above two range's value2？

Comment: Compare them in what respect? Equals? Shared elements? Sum of?

Comment: @Sayse  Compare Range.Value2

Answer (score 0):

What is r1? What is r2? are these cell values or a range of cell values.

In any case, Excel API will return to you either a mutli-dimensional array or the cells value in an unboxed manner (as an object rather than a specific type).

There is no easy way to compare the values, as the values in the spreadsheet could be of any type and it is your responsibility to figure out which types they are based on the spreadsheet you're working with. Something, we can't help you with.

Aside from that, once you get your return from Value2 you have to treat it like you would two arrays and compare each item 1 by 1.

Comment: ,r1 and r2 are both a range of cell values.and now i compare each item one by one,is there a faster or more simply method?

Comment: i don't think there is, and even if there was it would do the same thing underneath. you can try and parallelise it of course and compare a few items in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var firstRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
        var secondRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 200);
        var thirdRange = Enumerable.Range(180, 300);
        var fourthRange = Enumerable.Range(301, 400);

        Console.WriteLine(!IsContainInRange(firstRange, secondRange));      
        Console.WriteLine(!IsContainInRange(thirdRange, secondRange));
        Console.WriteLine(!IsContainInRange(fourthRange, secondRange));
    }

    private static bool IsContainInRange(IEnumerable<int> range1, IEnumerable<int> range2)
    {
        return (from r1 in range1
                 join r2 in range2 on r1 equals r2 
                 select r1).Any();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can compare two ranges without looping by making use of an Excel array-formula. The following code stores a value temporarily in cell A20, then produces a value of True or False to confirm if the ranges contain the same values. They are written in Excel **VBA**, but it should be possible to convert them to use Interop. `varCalc` (in the 2nd example) would be an Object rather than Variant.

```
Sub TestCompare()
    '{=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$4=$B$1:$B$4,1,0))=ROWS($A$1:$A$4)}
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim rngB As Range
    Dim blnTheSame As Boolean

    Set rngA = Range("$A$1:$A$4")
    Set rngB = Range("$B$1:$B$4")
    Range("A20").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(" & rngA.Address & "=" _
        & rngB.Address & ",1,0))=ROWS(" & rngA.Address & ")"
    blnTheSame = Range("A20").Value
    Range("A20").Clear
    MsgBox "Are they the same? " & blnTheSame
End Sub
```

The following version does the same, but works entirely in code, not requiring the use of a cell to store a temporary result:

```
Sub TestCompare2()
    '{=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$4=$B$1:$B$4,1,0))=ROWS($A$1:$A$4)}
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim rngB As Range
    Dim varCalc As Variant
    Dim blnTheSame As Boolean

    Set rngA = Range("$A$1:$A$4")
    Set rngB = Range("$B$1:$B$4")
    varCalc = "=SUM(IF(" & rngA.Address & "=" _
        & rngB.Address & ",1,0))=ROWS(" & rngA.Address & ")"
    blnTheSame = Evaluate(Array(varCalc))
    MsgBox "Are they the same? " & blnTheSame
End Sub
```

Neither make use of `Value2`, but I can't see that this is necessary for the comparison(s).

Comment: I downvoted because the question clearly says C#, not VB.